What is a value range for filesystem efficiency for btrfs with copying a file between directories?

There is no basic tool for Linux distributions for getting data rate or summary of data input/output for a directory (on a Linux filesystem).  

What is the percentage difference between a listed file size and and the real file size including all metadata related file description?
More in detail, what is the range in percentage for the difference between real file size, including low level disk io (e.g. accesses to metadata, journals) and listed file size from filesystem for OS for copying a tmp.txt file with (2^4)MB file content size from /tmp/tmp1 folder to /tmp/tmp2 folder on same disk partition and equal btrfs filesystem with a 4kB block size?
There are general filesystem dependent variations, being told from experience like

ext4: 5% to 15% overhead
XFS: 5% to 10% overhead
btrfs: 10% to 20% overhead
NTFS: 5% to 15% overhead
HFS+: 5% to 10% overhead
APFS: 10% to 20% overhead

(Percentages are rough estimates and can vary widely based on specific conditions and configurations. For precise measurements, benchmarking with specific workloads on the target hardware is recommended.)


What is a directory? What would you do with something like /mnt/nfs_remote_directory, /mnt/localSSD, /mnt/localHDD for example? How would you monitor writing to the /mnt directory if that has three different filesystems mounted under it? Whose rate would you want?

I think you're right: there's nothing that measures throughput for a (local) filesystem directory. With a systems administration hat on, it wouldn't be useful in the way that, say, throughput for a disk would be

Heh, I know what a directory is, I was asking what you meant. Have you considered the case I mentioned where a directory contains multiple different file systems? Can you explain your use case a bit more? Why would you ever be interested in this? Are you trying to monitor disk writing speed? Network transfer? I can't imagine why it would be useful to monitor a directory instead of a device, so if you explain why you need this, we might be able to provide a workaround.

The first kind of tools can be done generally. But the problem of the tools you are looking: they need to build in each file system (only file system know such data: do no expect IO disk activity after a call to a directory are all related to directories: file systems may do own stuffs). So you see the difficulty and so lack of tools.

Yes, but it has different purpose: The problem (as I wrote earlier) is linking directory access to disk access: things are no more synchronous and single tasked. Is a directory read causing an unrelated flush of caches?

For resource managements, I think disk level is the right level. But you are asking more about "profiling", and so I would setup VM for such tasks (and profiling often has penalities, but it could/should be done outside deployment environment. Or if you are doing some cloud providing feature, maybe you should add some code in kernel (specific for your use).

My point is that there is no such thing as a "directory" on Linux filesystems, everything is a file, and directories are abstract things that can contain very many different things inside them, so looking for the I/O speed of a directory doesn't make sense (to me, at least). I though that mentioning the case of mounted sub directories would demonstrate that. It just doesn't make sense to do this at the directory level, only at the filesystem level

Sure, that would show the sum total of all files whose inodes are considered part of the directory. I just don't understand why you would want to investigate the speed of I/O in the directory since that has no meaning by itself. Consider how much it is affected by I/O happening in other directories in the same filesystem, for example. But what I mostly wanted with my comment is to understand why you need this so we can provide the best possible solution to help you. This feels like it might be an XY problem.

@Stephen Kitt : i don't understand what is opinion based on this question anymore?

@beyondtime I’m having a hard time parsing your question title, but as far as I can tell it’s still asking for opinions. The question text might not be, but the title still is.

@all thanks for the helpful comments

I don't see the point of the current question. Isn't it something you can easily determine yourself? Just copy a bunch of files of different sizes, measure whatever it is you want to measure, and you get your range. It's like asking a bunch of randos on the internet what the size of your file is. Just find it out yourself

@muru How measure with a tool on linux the data rate and throughput for a directory on a filesystem?

What does that have to do with "listed file size and and the real file size including all metadata related file description"?

While further researching public search engines, a simple tool on GitHub was found, providing an approximate overview for a directory's data IO.
Maybe that's a starter for others looking for a Linux command line directory monitoring tool for

directory IO data rates and
total data IO for a period of time.

It does not separate or include low level disk IO access, but only file system-dependent data IO. There's a difference between disk IO and directory IO with read/write for metadata (e.g. iNodes listing, journaling logs) and block-related offsets between real file sizes and file system block sizes.
The ratio between metadata IO sizes and actual file sizes relate to a file system's performance and efficiency, therefore it might be interesting for file system performance comprehension getting measurement information for disk data IO and a directory's data IO (on various file system types).

for a simple and rough overview (e.g. no fs overhead meta data for specific filesystem types) one could utilize du -a --block-size=1 and an additional du -a --block-size=1 --apparent-size and compare the difference between both results
